# How to print a line and type input in the same line

Tags: java

I want to print a line like this:

`Result: [the result are input here and after click on Enter to continue]`

How can I do that?

***EDIT:***

This is what I want:

```
Scanner user1 = new Scanner(System.in);

int x = user1.nextInt();

System.out.println("Result: "+x);
```

But the last line won't print unless I type my input and press Enter.

Comment: Please search for existing solutions before posting a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new at this.

Comment: No problem, just start by reading [help] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very old thread but since there doesn't seem to be an accepted answer, I am answering. Hope it would help someone else...
Here is what you are looking for

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
int num = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Hello you entered "+num);
```

Note that when you use println the cursor moves to next line.
If you use just print the next statement continues on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Using java, you simply could use `System.out.print();` to display it in console and after adding the capture info:

```
System.out.print("Result: ");
int x = user1.nextInt();
```

Comment: It didn't work, but maybe is another thing .. I wanna print a line with text and in the end will be the keyboard cursor waiting for my input (in the same line) ..

Comment: Added more code, in that way it should be working

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one will work. Please try

```
Input str =scanner. readLine("Result:" ) ;
Int inp =integer.parseInt(star) ;
```

Comment: I'm very new at coding and I don't understand how to use that, thank you to all, I think that I have to relax and go for the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The last line will not print unless you type an input and press enter as the code is run line by line. First you have to enter the value. Since it runs on console for the next step to be pressed you have to press enter. 
So whatever you said will naturally happen and cannot be avoided.
Based on the code snippet you sent there is nothing wrong with the code and the logic in it and these are basic java steps.